# How to make a calculation on multiple rows and sum up results

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, sum

I have a large excel sheet that I have replicated (much simpler version) below.  I want to have the cells in row 10 tell me, at each point in time in row 9, what the cost is.  So, right now the only project that has an "Actual End Date" is Project1 and it ended 1/31/2017.  This means row 10 will have a value of $1000 in cell B10 and the rest will be blank.  In row 11, I want to see the planned cost for each point in time in row 9.  So, for the 2/28/2017 column, I want there to be 25% * $5000 in the cell.  This is because through February, the project is only 25% done and has only accrued 25% of the costs. Row 12 will sum both of the previous rows.  Please keep in mind that this is only an example worksheet and the real will have multiple projects that overlap in the same time period.   Thanks for the help!!

Image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tplvh.png

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has/hasn't worked? `SumIfs()` may help, but what attempts have you made?

Comment: @BruceWayne I got the actual cost row working, but the planned cost row (11) is not.  I have tried a lot of things, including: sumifs, sum(if()), sumproduct, etc.  The current one I have that I thought should work in cell B11 is : `=SUM(IF((ISBLANK($d$2:$d$6))*($b$2:$b$6<b9)*( $c$2:$c$6>b9), (MAX((b9-$b$2:$b$6)/MAX($c$2:$c$6-$b$2:$b$6,1),0))*$E$2:$E$6), 0)`

Comment: Remember that my real file is very long and has all kinds of date ranges, so I need it to look in every row, do the calculation, and sum them all up at the end!

Answer (score 0):

For the planned cost, you can calculate the first value for 1/31/2017 independently. Rest is going to be the sum to the cell on the left plus the product from the appropriate row on the top. I am assuming your planned cost would also include cost that has already been incurred.